# How to extract information inside text files, inside rar files in python?

Tags: python, extract, rar

I have a .rar file say for example English-Lexicon.rar
Inside this .rar file, are two .txt files, i.e neg.txt and pos.txt. I need to access the contents inside the neg.txt and pos.txt using python. How can this be done? I'm fairly new to python.

Comment: Reading rar files from Python is a little tricky. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185959/read-content-of-rar-file-into-memory-in-python/1186041#1186041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used it, but [google](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&q=python+rar&oq=python+rar) came up with [rarfile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/).

Comment: I did install rarfile but I have no clue as to how to use this. And there isn't a documentation for it either.

Comment: @user1452759: The blurb on the front page says, `The interface is made as zipfile like as possible.`  Check out the [`Zipfile` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: The doc is located at https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html . And the reading speed is very slow compare to a direct read from file uncompressed file.